# create buttons for new row flutter

Tags: button, dynamic, dart, flutter

how do I create button to add a row and a delete button if one was added.
Like in contacts menu below
[Contact Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVtSm.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a sample on how you could do that and is not intended to be the full code. You can use a [ListView.builder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) in a [StatefulWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and add a [FormField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FormField-class.html) to the List everytime you click on the button. Same goes with removing it:

```
var items = [
  FormField(...),
]

class Some extends StatefulWidget{
  SomeState createState()=>  SomeState();
}

class SomeState extends State<Some> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget> [
        Expanded(child:
          ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return items[index];  
          }),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          text: new Text("someButton"), 
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              items.remove(FormField(...));
              items.add(FormField(...));
            })
          }
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```