# How to create buttons with for loop in a column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I need to implement lists of buttons in a column depending on the data entry. So, for that I have to use for loop. Each button requires two entires `id, text`. I can make it with List. But it accepts only string value not the integer.

This is the code I tried.

## code

```
Widget getTextWidgets(List<String> strings)
  {
    List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
    for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
        list.add(new ButtonForHome(
          lable: strings[i],
          onPressed: (){},
          ));
    }
    return new Column(children: list);
  }
```

I want to put `id` in onPressed event. How can I implement in the Flutter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create buttons for new row flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207666/create-buttons-for-new-row-flutter)

Comment: I think the answer is not what i am expecting. I need to create bunch of buttons, each accepts `id , text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nilesh Rathod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod) has indeed given the descriptive answer for the same. In flutter there is also, a way to achieve this, which is quite similar to `POJO class`, is

- To create own widget and specify the fields needs to be passed when we are using the widget
- Add the widget to the list, with the data specified for passing
- You can track, the id, by pressing itself also

I can clearly see that, you have created your own widget named as `ButtonForHome`, which takes in `label` for now. What you can do is, to make your widget takes in two argument, and you can do it like this:

```
class ButtonForHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final int id;  // this will save your day

  // @required will not let user to skip the specified key to be left null
  ButtonForHome({@required this.label, @required this.id});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       child: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            ),
            child: Text(this.label),
            onPressed: () => print(this.id) // Here you print your id using your button only
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**Now creating your button with a list, or adding via list**

- You can do it via `ListView.builder()`
- You can do it via your way, i.e., `List<Widget>.add()`

I am gonna show the solution in your way only:

```
Widget getTextWidgets(List<String> strings){
  List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();

  for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
    list.add(ButtonForHome(
      id: i, // passing the i value only, for clear int values
      label: strings[i]
    ));
  }

  return Column(children: list);
}
```

> With the new flutter in place, you don't need to do `new` every time while defining a widget. It understands now, so no need of `const`, `new` at all

So, wherever you populate your `getTextWidget`, it will show up the Widgte `ButtonForHome`, which has unique `id`, and `label`. Now the `ButtonForHome`, prints the `id` of that particular widget which was passed uniquely. So now, you can see your result happening.

I hope this is what you were looking for. Try it, and let me know.

Comment: It works. Only I need to change it `List<String> strings` to  `List<dynamic> strings` .Now all working.

Comment: Great @VikrantAgrahari. This is team work only! Keep learning :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Listview` instead of `Column`

SAMPLE CODE

```
 getTextWidgets() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: yourList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, itemIndex) {
          return MaterialButton(
              child: Text(yourList[itemIndex]),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint('Clicked index $itemIndex');
              });
        });
  }
```

Now your question

> I want to put id in onPressed event. How can I implement in the Flutter?

You can create a POJO class like this

```
class DataModel{
  String name;
  int id;
  DataModel(this.name, this.id);
}
```

Now create list of your POJO class

```
List<DataModel> list= List<DataModel>();
```

Now add data in your list like this

```
list.add(DataModel("name", 1));
list.add(DataModel("name", 2));
list.add(DataModel("name", 3));
```

Now you can use it like  this way

```
 getTextWidgets() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, itemIndex) {
          return MaterialButton(
              child: Text(list[itemIndex].name),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint('Clicked item name '+list[itemIndex].name);
                debugPrint('Clicked item ID '+list[itemIndex].id.toString());
              });
        });
  }
```

Comment: So, I am abit confused here now. How the list should be designed to have `id, value` in each entry. So that onPressed() can accept `id` as the link parameter.

Comment: @VikrantAgrahari check updated answer I have added another example

Comment: Great ! let me check this. I was using Map<int, String> instead of POJO class.

Comment: I am getting error in pushing data to `list` created with DataModel class.

Comment: can you please show me another example of pushing data into `list`.

Comment: `list ` cannot be called. that's what happening in my code

Comment: @VikrantAgrahari where you are declaring your `list`